# ASP.NET SqlDataSource filter behaviour

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a `GridView` object fed trough a `SqlDataSource`. In the same form I have also a number of `TextBoxes` used to build a filtering expression for the datasource. The *filtering* is started by pressing a `Button`.

```
<asp:GridView
    DataSourceID="sdsTable1"
    OnSorting="gvTable1_Sorting"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvTable1_PageIndexChanging"
    runat="server"
    CssClass="list_table"
    ID="_gvTable1"
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    EmptyDataText="No data."
    ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="true"
    AllowSorting="true"
    AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="10" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvTable1_RowDataBound" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
    <PagerSettings
        Visible="true"
        Mode="NumericFirstLast"
        PageButtonCount="3"
        Position="Bottom"
        NextPageText="Next page"
        PreviousPageText="Prev page"
        FirstPageText="First page"
        LastPageText="Last page" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="odd" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
         <HeaderTemplate>&nbsp;</HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <%#Eval("id")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="date">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <%#Eval("date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
          TOTALE:
         </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="price">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("price","{0:F2} &euro;") %>'>></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label
         </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsTable1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db.ProviderName %>"
    DataSourceMode="DataSet"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT id, id_user, price, description FROM view1 WHERE id_user = @id_user;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Type="Int32" Name="id_user" SessionField="USER_ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In codebehind (in the event hanlder associated with the `Button` mentioned above) I build up the filter expression chaining `TextBoxes` values, with this code:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_txtFilter0.Text.Trim()))
    {
        _sFilter += "(description LIKE '%" + _txtFilter0.Text.Trim() + "%')";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_txtFilter1.Text.Trim()))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_sFilter))
            _sFilter += " AND";

        _sFilter += "(description LIKE '%" + _txtFilter1.Text.Trim() + "%')";
    }

    sdsTable1.FilterExpression = _sFilter;
```

Everything works until I clear the fields that leads to an empty filter, im such circumstances I expected to retrieve all the records but for some reason, in this case, the last recordset is kept and shown apparently without a reason.

I tried also to disable the `SQLDataSource` caching feature without luck:

```
    EnableCaching="false"
```

I tried also to issue a `Select` command, again without luck:

```
 sdsTable1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: The backend server is MySQL

Comment: To be more precise the `SQLDataSource` use a `View` instead a table.

Comment: Looks like `_sFilter` is not getting set back to null if the search fields are cleared. It probably still contains the last filter clause because it only changes if the fields are NOT empty. Make sure you reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your _sFilter property will be persisted across postbacks, so as you're only updating it when your filter text boxes are *not* empty it will remain at the last set value when you clear them. Putting a breakpoint in your code at the line `_sdsTable1.FilterExpression = _sFilter;` should confirm this.

To solve the issue, either clear the _sFilter property before rebuilding it in your event handler, or write an additional check:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_txtFilter1.Text.Trim()) & string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_txtFilter0.Text.Trim()) )
{
  _sFilter = null;
}
```

Comment: @Crowcoder the real problem is not that... `_sFilter` was being reset to `""` each time the event handler was triggered. But you came really close to the real problem since to force `SQLDataSouce` to 'reset' I had to set `FilterExpression` to `null`... yet your solution was correct.